# How Can so many weapons from Saito's world exist in Halkeginia?

Tags: the-familiar-of-zero

Saito went to Halkeginia from a portal that appeared in front of him in normal world:

> At the time of the summoning, he had just picked up his laptop after attempting to get it repaired in Akihabara.
> Walking home a portal of some kind opened in front of him; and Saito's
> curiosity getting the better of him, he touched it and was sucked
> through.

After this, he traveled to Halkeginia and become Louise's familiar.

But this portal only appeared at Saito's world because Louise used [The Summoning spell](http://zeronotsukaima.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_spell), to summon a familiar (destiny?). At that time, nobody knew that Saito's world even existed.

So, how can be explained all other stuffs from his world that appeared in Halkeginia? Like all those weapons and airplanes used by him:

1. SIG Sauer P226

   [image]
2. M72 LAW

   [image]
3. A6M Zero fighter
4. Mitsubishi-F-2A
5. Flak 88 anti-aircraft/anti-tank gun

I didn't read their manga/novels, is it better explained there?

(Weapon names and images taken from [this](http://zeronotsukaima.wikia.com/wiki/Hiraga_Saito) Wiki).

Comment: I remember there being the setting where Japanese people from WW2 getting lost in Halkeginia. That was the reason why there was a plane for Saito to use at the end of season 2. Since there was one such case, it should not be to surprising to have a few more cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People and items cross over all the time.

Siesta is a descendant of a Japanese person who wound up there. She actively uses this in her attempts to win Saito over.

There's a Japanese girl's school uniform he gets a hold of (which he has the Princess put on, I think, since it fits her). There's a naughty magazine, as well. The girl who gave it to him thought it was some powerful, forbidden tome.

Saito tries to use the plane to cross over during an eclipse, but turns back to help Louise. The plane probably came through on a similar link between worlds. I vaguely recall the anime suggesting it was probably the exact same event, which occurred periodically every few decades.

In other words, the worlds are intrinsically linked by their nature, and the summoning spell just created a particular forced link. These crossed over relics are used to connect Saito to his old home, let him use Gandalfr powers on exotic (to the others) weapons, and comedic relief (forbidden tome = dirty magazine).